# Code Error : While running docker container with docker volume

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I am facing the below issue,

I have a docker container ( React APP ) running with volume attached to it. So that my code changes are reflected automatically and its working fine.

The docker compose file commands is as below

```
   volumes:
      - ".:/app"
      - "./src:/web/src"
      - "/app/node_modules"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "35729:35729"
```

Now what I have done is, I have created a clone of the same repo and pulled to my local machine into a  different folder. Now I am trying to run the container with

> docker-compose up -d --build

It spins up the container and replace the existing one, but throws a error  while app is running

> service-worker.js:26          Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed
> to fetch
> at service-worker.js:26:16 (anonymous) @ service-worker.js:26
>
> log.js:21 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS... main.chunk.js:10
> Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js): SassError: Can't find
> stylesheet to import.   ╷ 1 │ @import "./themes.scss";   │
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

But when I am commenting out the following line in volumes section in Docker-compose file and runs the docker-compose up command, there is no error and apps loads fine

> ```
>   - "./src:/web/src"
> ```

I tried removing the volumes after deleting the container and running it again. But when the above line is there in docker-compose it does not work.

Any idea how to resolve it and have volume attached ?

Comment: What I'm seen here is that the second volume is overwriting the first one  - ".:/app" --->everything in the root to app folder , second  by  - "./src:/web/src" ---src folder which also in the root to /web/src , just give a try by separating

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the directory or files where the volumes were stored and
run docker compose up --build -d not docker compose up -d --build